# Help digitally signing hashed (SHA1) string

Tags: c#, web-services, digital-signature

I'm posting data to REST URI, in the form of xml snippet with header and body. 
The body is encrypted, and then the header includes a digital signature (which is the encypted body hashed with SHA1 and then encrypted.
My question is, how do I create the signature. What is the method used to encrypt - I have been told to use the same shared key as used for the Rinjdael encrypted body.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the signing using RSA.

Here's a link: [How to: Sign XML Documents with Digital Signatures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229745(v=VS.85).aspx)

I'm not too sure on using the same key for the encryption as with the signing however, as RSA signing is a public/private key signing method, which allows the signature to be safely created using the private key, and safely verified on the client using the public key only.

As a supplement, Encryption != Hashing. SHA1 is a hashing algorithm, aka. a one-way non-reversible function. Encryption is reversible. Encryption is a two-way function.

Comment: You've got public and private keys mixed up. Also a signature involves both a Hash _and_ encryption.

Comment: @Henk - Gah thanks, fixed that. For the signature part, yeps, I know. I just don't know if the op knows the difference between the two, so I figured I'd add it.

Answer (score 1):

Signing involves asymmetric cryptography.

- The sender creates the hash and encrypts it with his **own private key** => signature
- The receiver decrypts the signature with the **public key** of the sender.
- The receiver hashes the received data and compares the local hash and the decrypted hash
- if they match the data is from the owner of the private key

So **No**, you don't use the (symmetric) Rijndael key.